# Move gameobject between two points with ease-in and ease-out

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a gameobject and a list of positions, it can be. Every time, I press a specific button, it should change its position. It should use the same speed to travel between the current position and the new position, regardless how long the distance between them is.

Although the travel speed should be everytime the same, at the start and the end, it should accelerate and decelerate smoothly.

This is my current code:

```
if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.KeypadPeriod))
            {

                foreach (GameObject element in wagons)
                {
                    element.GetComponent<wagonController>().trainDestinationDisplays.GetComponent<trainDestinationDisplayController>().trainOuterDisplayDestinationChanger(trainDestination);
                }

            }
```

and:

```
public void trainOuterDisplayDestinationChanger(string trainDestination)
    {
        foreach (GameObject element in destinationDisplaysOutside)
        {
            Vector3 newPos = new Vector3(element.transform.localPosition.x, -85, element.transform.localPosition.z);
            element.transform.localPosition = Vector3.Lerp(element.transform.localPosition, newPos, Time.deltaTime * 1);
        }

 
    }
```

First, I tried it with timeline animations, but there are not very flexible (I need to make an animation for every possible connection, like Travel von A to B, Travel von C to A, Travel von B to A and so on ...).

Then, I tried it with Vector3.lerp and it first felt like the solution, but it only goes one small step towards the target destination, every time I press. This was the code:

```
Vector3 newPos = new Vector3(transform.localPosition.x, -85, transform.localPosition.z);
transform.localPosition = Vector3.Lerp(transform.localPosition, newPos, Time.deltaTime * 1);
```

Then I read in an article, that lerp is not the right solution for smooth acceleration and deceleration, I should use SmoothDamp. In the example code it looked like this:

```
public Transform target;
    public float smoothTime = 0.3F;
    private Vector3 velocity = Vector3.zero;

    void Update()
    {
        Vector3 targetPosition = target.TransformPoint(new Vector3(0, 5, -10));

        transform.position = Vector3.SmoothDamp(transform.position, targetPosition, ref velocity, smoothTime);
    }
```

I don't get that code to work, I also don't understand the usage auf "velocity" - why is the velocity on zero?

Can someone push me in the right direction, how would be the best way to achieve my goal? I'm a litte confused right now ...

Comment: You are setting both target position and smooth position at update. Probably, that's the cause of problem. When I use SmoothDamp, I set target value in a property then update the smooth value and pass it to related function that way. If you don't have to get target position at update and you have a specific way point or can be determined in the outside of Update function, do it that way. Just move targetPosition variable to outside of Update and use SmoothDamp

Comment: I always got errors, when I moved it out. But after switching to Coroutine, as @derHugo pointed out, I don't have to work with update anymore :)

Answer (score 3):

Since I don't know all your scripts and types I will say what I would do - you can hopefully implement it then the way you want/need it ;)

---

First of all I would suggest to rather use a [Coroutine](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Coroutines.html) which is way better to control and maintain than doing everything in `Update`.

Then note that [`Vector3.SmoothDamp`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3.SmoothDamp.html) will be no use for your goal. It damps the velocity over time causing ease-out for the movement. But **it does not add any ease-in.**

So I would rather stick to [`Vector3.Lerp`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3.Lerp.html).

---

Lets's say for now you have given a list of your checkpoints, the current index and your basic average velocity in Unity units/second:

```
List<Vector3> checkpoints;
int index;
float velocity;
```

then you can have a method to start a new animation towards the next (using the index) checkpoint in your list and block any concurrent animations

```
private bool alreadyMoving;

public void MoveToNext()
{
    if(alreadyMoving) return;

    index++;
    if(index >= checkpoints.Count) return;

    var nextTargetPosition = checkpoints[index];
    
    // Start moving smooth to the target position
    StartCoroutine(MoveToTargetSmooth(nextTargetPosition));
}
```

And now to the magic

```
private IEnumerator MoveToTargetSmooth(Vector3 targetPos)
{
    // block concurrent routines
    if(alreadyMoving) yield break;

    alreadyMoving = true;

    if(velocity <= 0)
    {
        Debug.LogError($"{nameof(velocity)} may not be negative or 0", this);
        // Allow the next routine to start now
        alreadyMoving = false;
        yield break;
    }

    // pre-cache the initial position
    var startPos = transform.position;

    // using the given average velocity calculate how long the animation
    // shall take in total
    var distance = Vector3.Distance(startPos, targetPos);

    if(Mathf.Approximately(distance, 0))
    {
        Debug.LogWarning("Start and end position are equal!", this);
        // Allow the next routine to start now
        alreadyMoving = false;
        yield break;
    }

    var duration = distance / velocity;

    var timePassed = 0f;
    while(timePassed < duration)
    {
        // This factor moves linear from 0 to 1
        var factor = timePassed / duration;
        // This adds ease-in and ease-out 
        // see https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Mathf.SmoothStep.html
        // Basically you can use ANY mathematical function that maps
        // the input of [0; 1] again to a range of [0;1] 
        // with the easing you like
        factor = Mathf.SmoothStep(0, 1, factor);

        // And this is how finally you use Lerp in this case
        transform.position = Vector3.Lerp(startPos, targetPos, factor);

        // This tells Unity to "pause" the routine here
        // render this frame and continue from here in the next one
        yield return null;

        // increase by the time passed since last frame
        timePassed += Time.deltaTime;
    }

    // just to be sure to end with clean values
    transform.position = targetPos;


    // Allow the next routine to start now
    alreadyMoving = false;
}
```

---

Instead of `Mathf.SmoothStep` you can use any mathematical function that maps the values between `0` and `1` to the desired curve ([here](https://www.febucci.com/2018/08/easing-functions) are some examples).

Or if you want to go super fancy you can also use an [`AnimationCurve`](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/animeditor-AnimationCurves.html) like e.g.

```
[SerializeField] private AnimationCurve yourAnimationCurve;
```

and configure it via the Inspector exactly according to your needs

[image]

and then as a factor use  [`AnimationCurve.Evaluate`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AnimationCurve.Evaluate.html)

```
factor = timePassed / duration;
factor = yourAnimationCurve.Evaluate(factor);
```

---

*Note: Typed on smartphone but I hope the idea gets clear*

Comment: That worked really well, thank you very much! Also thank you for typing so much info on a smartphone :)

Is there a way to make the acceleration/decelaration phase longer/smoother?

Comment: @hdbrnd as said instead of `Mathf.SmoothStep` you basically can use **any** mathematical function that builds a curve between 0 and 1 according to your needs. See e.g. [here](https://www.febucci.com/2018/08/easing-functions) for other easing functions

Comment: Thanks for the further explanation and the link!

Comment: @hdbrnd if you want to go super fancy you can also use an [`AnimationCurve`](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/animeditor-AnimationCurves.html) and configure it via the Inspector exactly according to your needs and then as a factor use e.g. [`factor = yourAnimationCurve.Evaluate(factor);`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AnimationCurve.Evaluate.html)

Comment: Sorry, I've missed your comment. That is pretty awesome, thanks for that addition :)

Answer (score 0):

SmoothDamp you tried is indeed a very good way to do it. Velocity parameter is an additional variable that the method (which is static), needs to operate, it stores (and mofidies) information about the velofcity of change, so it starts with zero, and accelerates, so with each iteration it accelerates towards target as long as the difference is large, and starts to deccelerate as you approach your target. Smoothdamp is guaranteed not to have overshoot, but you could also engineer a solution that overshoots and give you this wiggly harmonic oscillation at the end, if your damping is not high enough.

For an even simpler solution, if you know your start point and end point in advance, you can use Mathf.SmoothStep, which is essentially an S-Curve, that gives pretty much the same result as SmoothDamp, and you can very easily intergrate into existing code, but it doesn't work so well if you intend to change your target while the motion has already started

Your code looks that it should work, are you sure your target is computed correctly?